# unable to fit text in TableRow in android

Tags: android, textview, android-tablelayout

I am quite new to android and i am designing a Table layout with every row containing two                           textviews.The problem is that the text in textview gets truncated if text is long.I have used wrap content and applied weight also but not help me .The code for layout is below

```
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            style="@style/fill_parent_wrap_content" >

            <TableRow style="@style/both_wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/InfoTextView1"
                    android:text="@string/customerName"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDetailCustomerName"
                    style="@style/InfoTextView1" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow style="@style/both_wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/InfoTextView1"
                    android:text="@string/caNumberDetail"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDetailCaNo"
                    style="@style/InfoTextView1" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow style="@style/both_wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/InfoTextView1"
                    android:text="@string/customerAddress"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDetailAddress"
                    style="@style/InfoTextView1"
                    />
            </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</Scrollview>


    This is a style that i apply to textviews
   <style name="InfoTextView1">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
 <TableRow 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:weightSum="2">

  <TextView 
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
   <TextView 
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:ellipsize="marquee"/>

   </TableRow>
```

Then put this line in java file `textview.setSelected(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Show the style for the TableLayout and TableRows...

I bet the problem is on them.

Comment: <style name="both_wrap_content">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

Comment: <style name="fill_parent_wrap_content">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>